# Ubuntu 16 Eclipse CPP - Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu

I am using Eclipse (Luna 4.4.1) on Ubuntu to run a `.cpp`.

Before the program event starts I receive the following error message:

> ```
> Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault
> ```

It is happening on the first line of my main function and doesnt let me run anything:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string a = "test\n";
    cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As-is this should not cause the error. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: So what are you including and what are you linking to make it crash.